# Correct sscanf() prototype, "int sscanf ( const char * s,const char * format, ...);" or int sscanf (char * s,const char * format, ...);?

Tags: c, arrays, constants, scanf

Here is the prototype for the `sscanf()` function as described in the `cplusplusreference`([link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/)) :

```
 int sscanf ( const char * s, const char * format, ...);
```

But I find something fishy about it.Not only does the type of first argument differ from many other string library functions like `strcpy()`([1](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/)) and `strcat()`([2](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/)) (`const char*` vs `char*`),but it also seems odd how can we make the array pointed by the first argument constant when the very purpose of the function is to write to it(alter the contents of the array) using that pointer!!

I mean, in `int sscanf (const char * s,const char * format, ...);` aren't we telling through the `const` qualifier that we can't change the array pointed by `s` using `s`? Is that a typo on that site, or do I fail to understand something?Please explain.

Comment: Vote to close as OP wishes it deleted and it won't really help anyone in the future.

Comment: You can find the correct prototype in the POSIX specification of [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Is it ok if I refer to that link you gave henceforth instead of Cplusplusreference?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler One more thing.How to pronounce %d,%f,%hu etc?Presently I pronounce them as  `percentage dee`,`percentage eff`,`percentage ech you` etc.

Comment: The POSIX site is pretty good — it includes the C99 standard library functions (some of them are extended by POSIX, including the `scanf()` family specifically, but the extensions are clearly marked).  AFAIK, it is OK to link to it; at worst, you're supposed to register (free) to use it.  On pronunciation, I use _percent dee_ etc. but I doubt anyone would have difficulty understanding 'percentage' instead of 'percent'.

Comment: The best starting point at the POSIX site is: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Combined with your feedback,I have now some other reason to stop using `cplusplusreference` **altogether**.Can you kindly tell if the `int firstchar = (int) '#';` part in the program in the following page is **TOTALLY NOT NEEDED**? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vsprintf/  I can't believe how a site claiming to be a reputed one can have such silly typos.That line is totally not needed right?I feel so,but I want you to confirm.

Comment: One of the differences between C and C++ is that in C, `'#'` is an `int` value, but in C++, it is a `char` value.  (In C, `sizeof('#')` returns 4, usually, but in C++, it returns 1 always.). Looking at the one line in isolation, in a C++ program, there is a widening conversion in the definition and initialization line. Given that it is a widening conversion, the cast really isn't needed — but the conversion does occur in C++ (whereas in C, there is no conversion so the cast is wholly redundant). In the slightly larger context, the variable `firstchar` is unused — it _is_ completely unneeded.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Off-topic,but please settle it here for me.I've these  things at the end of my **C File I/O** chapter--`open()`,`read()`,`write()` under the section `"Low-level I/O"`.I googled and it seems they are system calls of `unix-like` **OS**'es and not standard C.Am I right?They are not part of C(standard C) right?(for example,there would be something other than `open()` in Windows for the same job,right?)Please tell this much only to me to end this conversation.If you say yes,I'll leave that section as that won't be needed for the moment as I've time constraints.

Comment: Correct: `open()`, `close()`, `read()`, `write()` etc are not in Standard C.  They are the core functions used on POSIX (Unix-like) systems to implement the C standard `fopen()`, `fclose()`, `fread()`, `fwrite()` and other standard I/O functions.  They're not a part of Windows that Microsoft supports keenly; you have to prefix the names with an underscore to get at them for reasons that seem good enough to Microsoft but spurious to me.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `spurious`!! LOL.Anyways,thanks for the reply.You saved me a great lot of trouble and time.Glad that I got my answer so fast.Sincere thanks again.Bye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const char * s`

`sscanf` does not write anything to the `s` string, `s` is an input string.

Comment: I think I need to get some proper sleep.I realize my mistake.It's so embarrassing.Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In strcpy and strcat, the first argument (the destination) isn't const, because, of course, the function will modify them.

Generally, in function which modify a string, the first argument is the destination.

So, the correct prototype of sscanf is "int sscanf ( const char * s, const char * format, ...);", because it won't modify the source string, just read it.

If you aren't sure of the prototype of a function, the man page about this function is the reference

Answer (score 0):

the purpose of making the first argument as constant for the function is to ensure that the function dosent in any manner or way change the contents of the string s during invokation .... it's to provide something like a read only access to the string s .....

the syntax seems fine.

still in doubt check in man.... or any C book .

Answer (score 0):

By C99, the scanf prototype is:

```
int scanf(const char* restrict s, const char* restrict format, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this prototype:

```
int sscanf ( const char * s, const char * format, ...);
```

- The `int` is a read-only output, the field match count or error report.
- The `const char *s` is a *read-only* source from which characters are read.
- The `const char *format` is a read-only specification of what the writable targets are.
- The `...` will become the list of writable addresses the output from the conversion go into, as detailed by `format`.

So, accordingly, the *input* string of `s` can certainly be a read-only string, since it's fairly important that `sscanf` be trusted not to overwrite the thing.